# I can't get CircleAvatar to be anything but an oval when I assigned a backgroundImage

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to build out a basic ListView filled with ListTiles, and have a CircleAvatar (either leading or trailing) with a photo in it.

My code is:

```
  body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 18,
    itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: ListTile(
          trailing: 
             CircleAvatar(
              radius: 50.0,
              // child: Text('hi'),
              backgroundImage: 
              AssetImage(
                'assets/images/Survivor-12.jpg',
              ),
            ),
          title: Text('Name of the Person $i'),
          subtitle: Text('Assigned to: Bob'),
          leading: Text(i.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
        ),
      );
    },
```

The output however is like this:
[image]

How can I get the image to be an actual circle? If I remove it and replace it with a Text widget it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the image to be in actual circle, you can wrap your CircleAvatar Widget inside of a Container Widget and use decoration property to define its shape as below.

```
 ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 18,
    itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: ListTile(
          trailing: Container(
            height: 55.0,
            width: 55.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 30.0,
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                  'https://buildflutter.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/buildflutter_255.png'),
            ),
          ),
          title: Text('Name of the Person $i'),
          subtitle: Text('Assigned to: Bob'),
          leading: Text(i.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ListTile(
          trailing: ClipOval(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              height: 70,
              width: 100,
              child: Image.network(
                imageUrl[0],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          title: Text('Name of the Person $i'),
          subtitle: Text('Assigned to: Bob'),
          leading: Text(i.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the list-type container changes the rendering: if I change a `ListView()` for a `Column()`, the `CircleAvatar` renders correctly in my application.

There's a hint in the [ListView docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html):

> In the cross axis, the children are required to fill the ListView.

To solve this here I wrapped my `CircleAvatar` in a `Row` which will fill the horizontal space of the `ListView`, and adjusted the contents of the `Row` accordingly. The `ListTile` may need further jiggling to get it to correctly emulate a `Row`.

```dart
ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 60.0,
          backgroundImage: avatarImage ?? avatarImage,
        ),
      ],
    ),
    //...
  ],
);
```